# Sharing ArcObjects/ArcGIS snippets?

Tags: discussion, code

Can we make an attempt to share snippets here directly which we think can be used regularly?

For example, adding shapefile programmatically, or buffer etc.

Comment: Well, we could do things like that - do you have anything you'd like to add?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if it is the best way to answer the question being asked.

Answer (score 3):

As Regan said, the best place for snippets is in context of the problem they're built to solve, that is, in answer to a question.

If the snippet is too large to integrate cleanly into an answer there are couple of 3rd party places I know of, no doubt there are others:

- http://gis.pastebin.com/ - currently empty. Pastebin.com has automatic namespaces based on sub-domain. Pro: stability, Pastebin has been around since 2002. Con: *"you can store text for a certain period of time"*, said time is unspecified.
- http://snipplr.com/ - allows starring favourites, comments, language specific searching, tags. A relatively new service (2006).

For people who do decide to use a snippet service, I would ask that the most relevant part of the code, the keystone idea, be replicated in the answer itself. This provides resilience in the face of broken links and, more importantly, educates. The what and why of a method are it's most important features. The how can be replicated if the principles are known.

Comment: both these sites are blocked where I work :(

Answer (score 1):

Isn't http://resources.arcgis.com/content/all-galleries the best place for that?

**August 2019** https://codesharing.arcgis.com/

Comment: ...for arcgis .

Comment: Which is the program you would use snippets of ArcObjects code in.

Comment: This link appears to be broken.

Comment: it's not broken but in an archive state "This is an archive of older help systems." a newer link is https://codesharing.arcgis.com/

Answer (score -1):

I would think that would be a good use of the community wiki feature.